# Can't edit existing terms and conditions

Tags: magento-2.1, terms-and-conditions

I created a *terms and conditions* entry in my Magento 2.1.8 installation. It's showing up in the checkout and works as expected (on the frontend).

#### But...

When I attempt to edit the existing terms of use, I'm given a blank screen, with only the option to delete or save the terms.

[image: Empty Terms of Use]

Is this intended behavior? It seems counter-intuitive to have to delete the TOS and recreate it every time a change is made.

Comment: Nope, is not the default behavior. Maybe you try to deploy static files again for admin... php bin/magento setup:static-content:deploy --area adminhtml

Comment: Redeploying static assets and clearing the cache didn't have any effect. Any other suggestions?

Comment: Check the browser console for errors.